# Pandas CSV txt no commas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

i try to take data from .txt and merge with table from csv
data in txt is int
data in csv is objects.
i tryed to transform my data to object and merge it. values of .txt dont match with id.
i want take weights values to my part_number but its NaN. Cant get why it so...
I think mb something with data types.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX09K.png)

```
`from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd 
import os
import glob



data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=';')
prices = pd.read_csv('price.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=';')#reading data
deposits = pd.read_csv('deposit.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=';')
weights = pd.read_csv("weight.txt",on_bad_lines='skip',sep='\s+')#PROBLEMS
#weights = pd.read_csv("weight.txt",on_bad_lines='skip',sep='\s+',dtype={'weight_packed':object, 'weight_unpacked': object, 'part_number': object})#also tryed something like that but still the same
weights.part_number = weights.part_number.astype(str)
quantity = pd.read_csv('quantity.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=';')

combined = pd.DataFrame()
temp= pd.DataFrame()
temp1 = pd.merge(data, prices, how='left', on="part_number")#data and prices
temp=pd.merge(temp1,quantity, how='left',on="part_number") #data/price/quantity 
combined=pd.merge(temp,deposits,how='left',on="part_number")#data/price/quantity/deposits
temp3=pd.merge(combined,weights,how='left',on="part_number")#PROBLEMS ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns.
combined=temp3
values = {"deposit": 0,}
combined=combined.fillna(value=values)#deposits with 0s
combined[combined['warehouse'].isin(['A', 'H', 'J', '3', '9'])] #check if items on chosen location
combined.loc[combined.quantity =='>10','quantity'] = 10 #deleting > from quantity


values = {"quantity": 666,}
combined=combined.fillna(value=values)#deleting NaN from quantity
combined = combined.loc[combined['quantity'] != 666]
combined
`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include the error message your code is producing

Comment: it looks like the mean pain is weight.txt, - would suggest to share part/example of its data